# How to get resources in .jar?

Tags: java, jar

I use [this](http://www.sourcestream.com/programming-stuff/java-http-server) HttpServer class.
What can I do to set `WEB_ROOT` to a resource inside the .jar file?

I tried to make so,

```
static final File WEB_ROOT = new File(HttpServer.class.getResource("www"));
```

but I have error "no suitable constructor found for File(URL)".

Compilaton

```
~$ javac HttpServer.java
```

Create jar file

```
~$ jar cfe http.jar HttpServer HttpServer.class ./www/
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retrieve the file inside the jar, use:

```
InputStream is = HttpServer.class.getResourceAsStream("www");
```

alternatively

```
      static File WEB_ROOT = null;
static {
    try {
        WEB_ROOT = new File(HttpServer.class.getResource("www").toURI());
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

but is NOT a good idea to make it static.

Comment: HttpServer.java:19: error: unreported exception URISyntaxException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
  static final File WEB_ROOT = new File(HttpServer.class.getResource("www").toURI());

Comment: up---dated see now, but avoid this static way

Comment: If the file or directory that you requested is inside a jar, you'll get a jar: URL instead of a file: URL. You can't pass a jar: URL to the `File` constructor.

Comment: `File file = new File(webRoot, fileRequested);`

webRoot is a object of www root directory inside the .jar file.